# New tab VS OOP : which is better in Arduino

Tags: c++

In C++, I understand that you can "multi-file" program and in Arduino, open a new tab. [This is what I mean by file.](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/18-programs-with-multiple-files/) Then, there is **O**bject **O**riented **P**rogramming or OOP for short (like with a `.cpp` and `.h` file.

Which of these 2 is a better method for splitting your code into multiple files? OOP seems more popular, but is also harder, but is there any real benefits for it?

I'm new to the world of OOP so **please** write an answer like if you would explain it to a newb! Also, I'm quite adventurous and so don't let difficulty change you anwsers bias!

*For those that want to close this question as off-topic, note that SO closed it in less then 10 minutes.*

Comment: Comparing both are like comparing bananas and apples. None is better than the other. Both are complementary. OOP is a real programming *paradigm*. Multifile is in no way a programming paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.cpp` and `.h` is *not* OOP. That is just splitting things into files. OOP is the use of classes and namespaces, etc. Those can be used just in one file alone.

What you are asking is actually is it better to make a *Library* or to have multiple files in your sketch. This has absolutely nothing to do with OOP.

In general:

- If you think you may need the code in other sketches then making it a library can be good.
- If it is distinct code that will only ever be used in the one sketch there is no point in going to the effort of making a library.

Once the code is compiled it makes little or no difference if it's in a "tab" or if it's in a "library".

Comment: Let's say for a competition robot, with multiple programmers, what would you suggest?

Comment: @DatHa That question is meaningless. Libraries can make managing complex code easier since you have distinct modules. But editing libraries means working outside the IDE, which generally makes life harder. If there is no specific reason to make a library then the question "should you make a library" is entirely your own subjective personal choice.

Comment: @DatHa If you are working collaboratively then possibly using libraries may make the sharing of code easier, since each library could be unit tested individually and delegation of work to other people can be done on a per-library basis if you like. However much the same can be said of spitting into other files anyway.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different techniques; one of programming, the other of managing files. They are independent of one another; you an apply either, both, or neither, as fits the situation.

A true OO design starts from the beginning of the project, finds the commonalities among the kinds of data that will be managed by the finished product, and abstracts away the most common of those into one or more base classes, from which the more specific classes will be derived. OOP is a whole course of study.

An OK first approximation is simply to create data objects as you go. This lets you hide private information - those details of the object that depend on how you implement that object, but aren't real attributes of the real-world object the data-object represents. This is sometimes called "C with classes".

Based on your statement that you are "new to the world of OOP", I expect this will be your most effective strategy.

Dividing your code into files or modules by grouping those functions dealing with, say, stepper motors into one pair of files (stepper.c++, stepper.h), and those dealing with ultrasonic sensors into another pair (usound.c++/.h), etc. is a perfectly good way to organize your code into files, once your body of code gets too big to keep it one file effectively. This doesn't necessarily hide the private, implementation information although you can do that, too, very effectively with file-level static variables and static functions.

C++ was originally implemented as a pre-processor that emitted pure C constructs from C++ syntax. Which means: Whatever you can do in C++, you could also do in C. The only difference is the details are all right there in the open for anyone to see. C++ puts more of them "behind the curtain".

If you have a good handle on writing C- or C++-with-classes, make good use of static variables and functions, and good choices about what might best be grouped with what into your separate files, you'll be pretty well prepared to take on the additional concepts of OOP.